# How to work with interfaces and JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, interface, java-ee-6

I should start out by saying that I am fairly new to Java EE and that I do not have a strong theoretical background in Java yet.

I'm having trouble grasping how to use `JPA` together with `interfaces` in Java. To illustrate what I find hard I created a very simple example.

If I have two simple interfaces `Person` and `Pet`:

```
public interface Person
{
    public Pet getPet();
    public void setPet(Pet pet);
}

public interface Pet
{
    public String getName();
}
```

And an Entity `PersonEntity` which implements `Person` as well as a `PetEntity` which implements `Pet`:

```
@Entity
public class PersonEntity implements Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private PetEntity pet;

    @Override
    public void setPet(Pet pet)
    {
        /* How do i solve this? */
    }
}

@Entity
public class PetEntity implements Pet
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    /* Getters and Setters omitted */

}
```

How do I properly handle the case in the `setPet` method in which I want to persist the relationships between the two entities above?

The main reason I want to use interfaces is because I want to keep dependencies between modules/layers to the public interfaces. How else do I avoid getting a dependency from e.g. my ManagedBean directly to an Entity?

If someone recommends against using interfaces on entities, then please explain what alternatives methods or patterns there are.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`targetEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#targetEntity%28%29) property in the relationship annotation.

```
@Entity
public class PersonEntity implements Person {
    private Long id;

    private Pet pet;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = PetEntity.class)
    public Pet getPet() {
        return pet;
    }        

    public void setPet(Pet pet) {
        this.pet = pet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it will work? You're using implicit field access, but set the `@OneToOne` annotation on the setter. Moreover, even with the property access, will this annotation work? Shouldn't it be on getter rather than setter?

Comment: Mairbek, and what about mixing field na property access? Do you think that this part of JPA 2.0 spec is relevant in this case: *"The behavior of applications that mix the placement of annotations on fields and properties within an entity hierarchy without explicitly specifying the Access annotation is undefined."*?

Comment: Works as long as there is only 1 implementation of Person of course. When you have more than 1 then you would need explicit support in the implementation for interface fields