# Eclipselink Exception after Migration from GF 3.1.2 to Payara 4.1.1

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, payara

I am migrating a project form GF 3.1.2 (Eclipselink 2.3.2) to Payara 4.1.1.162 (Eclipselink 2.6.2).

During the deployment of my war archive I get the following exception:

```
[2016-05-10T15:58:35.406+0200] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1462888715406] [levelValue: 1000] [[javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
```

Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [objsetupDB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2026)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:926)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:435)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [objsetupDB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.ecli]]

[2016-05-10T15:58:35.406+0200] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1462888715406] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  pse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.preInitialize(MetamodelImpl.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.preInitializeMetamodel(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2012)
    ... 73 more]]

[2016-05-10T15:58:35.408+0200] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1462888715408] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while preparing the app]]

[2016-05-10T15:58:35.408+0200] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1462888715408] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [objsetupDB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2026)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:926)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:435)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [objsetupDB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.preInitialize(MetamodelImpl.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.preInitializeMetamodel(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2012)
    ... 73 more
]]

[2016-05-10T15:58:35.421+0200] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1462888715421] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [objsetupDB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [objsetupDB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2026)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:926)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:435)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.preInitialize(MetamodelImpl.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.preInitializeMetamodel(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2012)
    ... 73 more
]]

[2016-05-10T15:58:35.593+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1462888715593] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [objsetupDB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.EntityTypeImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MappedSuperclassTypeImpl. Please see server.log for more details. ]]

In the project we are using a hierarchy of MappedSuperclasses like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityBase implements IEntity {
...
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class StandardEntityJpaImpl extends EntityBase implements IStandardEntity {
...
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ArtifactBase extends StandardEntityJpaImpl {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="artifact")
public class Artifact extends ArtifactBase implements Comparable<Artifact> {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="artifact2")
public class Artifact2 extends ArtifactBase implements Comparable<Artifact>    {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="artifact3")
public class Artifact3 extends ArtifactBase implements Comparable<Artifact> {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="reference")
public class Reference extends StandardEntityJpaImpl implements Comparable<Artifact> {
...
}
```

The hierarchy is the following:

```
   [Persistence Model][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uynO.png
```

I already set the logging in Payara to FINEST, but unfortunately I do not get any further inforamtion. I also tried to deploy the Eclipselink jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder, but that did not change the behaviour. Has onyone an idea why there is a ClasscastException?

Thanks for your help,
Bernd

Comment: Try removing the Inheritance annotation, as a table per class inheritance strategy doesn't make sense on a MappedSuperclass - any entities extending the superclass automatically get their own table.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. The error is still the same.

Comment: You will need to show the Internal exception's stack trace then, and your model extending the Artifact class.  Top answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226392/multiple-mappedsuperclass shows a similar model as working and explains why the inheritance annotations needs to be moved down the chain, but you'll need to see how your model is different to figure out why you get this exception.

Comment: I added the stacktrace, a class diagarm and additional code.

Comment: Are all your classes listed within the persistence unit?  Seems like one or more mappedsuperclasses aren't being found and processed during the predeployment - turn on EclipseLink logging and mark each of the classes as they get picked up and processed.  The error should occur while processing a particular class which will help isolate what is going wrong.  Also seems like a bug/feature would be appropriate ,as EclipseLink should throw a better error indicating the problem if it can't handle something in the structure.

Comment: I am using only one persistence unit and all my classes are listed in the persistence.xml. The entity classes are located in different jars, but that should not harm. I already swichted on eclipselink logging, but there is unfortunately no additional information available.

Comment: If you aren't seeing logs from the persistence unit deploying from EclipseLink, then logging isn't setup correctly - you likely configured EclipseLink default logging, but the server log is being used.  Glassfish uses log4j property files to config logging which you need to enable, or you can just specify EL use its default logger by adding <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger"/>

Comment: I turned on the logging , but I cannot see any suspicios entries:

Answer (score 2):

I went to the eclipselink sources and it seems  that it expects a mapped superclass but finds a normal entity class for some reason ([the relevant line of code in sources](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/2.6.2/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/metamodel/MetamodelImpl.java#L398)).

It seems that the normal entity class is found because there is no descriptor for mapped superclass provided ([the relevant line of code in sources](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/2.6.2/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/metamodel/ManagedTypeImpl.java#L437)

However, it seems that this is a bug in eclipselink, as it adds mapped superclass descriptors into a map with fully qualified class name as a key, but then it cannot find it in the same map under the class name, which is retrieved from the values inside the map. I don't see a reason why this happens.

Comment: I got this issue on Intellij, I was trying to change my netbeans project to intellij.. And now i'm not able to use it cause of this..

Comment: @ChristianMoen, try reading my other answer, it might be helpful to you, as it describes the real problem confirmed by Bernd.

Answer (score 0):

I discussed with Bernd offline, and we discovered that the error is because an interface, which is implemented by an entity, is mapped as a JPA superclass (via ORM mapping in ORM XML, probably after refactoring).

Interfaces should not be mapped as superclasses nor entities, as they don't carry any value. You should map classes that implement the interface instead (i.e. com.siemens.energy.td.common.i18n.I18nTextImpl). In your case, the mapping of the list field is already specified for the implementing class, so no other change should be necessary.

If you use interfaces as value types inside entities, you might need to use targetEntity attribute with mapping annotations (like OneToMany). At least in case there is more than one entity that implements the interface. Have a look at this page for more into and examples: [How to work with interfaces and JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964799/how-to-work-with-interfaces-and-jpa)